# Save gif to android gallery

Tags: android, gif, android-gallery, android-ion

Using https://github.com/koush/ion image Loader to display gif files into ImageView

I save the **jpg** images into gallery by this code

```
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                                    getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap,
                                    "XXX", "Image1");
```

but this way is not working with gif files.

Do you have any idea how can i accomplish this?

Comment: I answered it here. thanks. [visit this url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53854746/5923085)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save gif using this code

```
  File file = new File(getBaseContext().getExternalCacheDir(),
                    "gif_name"+ ".gif");
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(gif.getData());//gif is gif image object
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This code will save the gif in cache directory on your external sd card but will not be visible in Gallery.

Comment: gif.getData() where to get this method

Comment: Gif represents the actual gif that you fetch from a api

Comment: my gif file is located in external storage and I have the path i.e. /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<PackageName>/files/<FolderName>/xyz.gif. Now I want to Save/copy this file to Image Gallery and show there. How to do this. Because I didn't get the .getData() method not from String imagePath and not from file.

Comment: First tell me where to get this methd getData() and then How to make this visible in Gallery ?

Answer (score 2):

Bitmaps are single images, so GIFs will not work with this API. To save a GIF, you'll need to download the gif to a file on external storage, and then notify MediaScanner to scan it. It will then show up in the gallery.