# How to save GIF image in sdcard?

Tags: android

I am new android and I want to save GIF image in sdcard through android programming. Currently I had done some code from google to save GIF image in sdcard. But When I am saving that image to sdcard it will display normal image not GIF Image.

Here this is my code to display GIF image

```
//Save code
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.gpp3);
            File outputFile = new File("/sdcard/gpp3.gif");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (fos != null) {
                AnimatedGifEncoder gifEncoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
                gifEncoder.start(fos);
                gifEncoder.addFrame(image);
                gifEncoder.finish();
            }

        }
    });
```

So,What is the problem in above code.Please tell me.

Comment: https://github.com/madmaw/animatedgifencoder/

Comment: Do not use BitmapFactory at all. Do not use AnimatedGiffEncoder. You have already a gif image in drawables i suppose. So just copy it to the file system.

Comment: @greenapps when i using your way it will display .jpg extension and image is .gif

Comment: @greenapps see my changes https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a9dbd1b342356b6b18a395925d80e636

Comment: `when i using your way it will display .jpg extension and image is .gif` ??? Impossible. That is not my way!  As it is you who determines the file name. Of course you should not convert to a Drawable or Bitmap first. Or use the MediaStore. You should also post your code here.  What i told you in my first comment is to save the byte array from resource directly to file. Open an InputStream from your resource and copy to a FileOutputStream.

Comment: Until now you did not confirm that `R.drawable.gpp3` is a gif image already. It is important that it is. Otherwise my words do not make sense.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure but as per your requirement you should first open your GIF and then after you convert into byte array then after you save it.i hope you will get your solution

```
private void saveGIF()
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "shared_gif_shai" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, url open connection");

            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.g);
            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, url get input stream");
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, create buffered input stream");

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, create buffered array output stream");

            byte[] img = new byte[1024];

            int current = 0;

            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, write byte to baos");
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(current);
            }


            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, done write");

            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, create fos");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baos.toByteArray());

            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, write to fos");
            fos.flush();

            fos.close();
            is.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, done write to fos");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And also Give this permission in you **AndroidMenifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: it's perfectly working for me.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the provide code and make sure to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in meaifest.

```
 protected void saveGifToInternalStorage(String fileName, URL url) {
    try {
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/your_app_name";
        File file = new File(PATH);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, "download begining");
        Log.d(TAG, "download url:" + url);
        Log.d(TAG, "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName+".gif");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "download ready in"
                + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                + " sec");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);
    }
}
```